# Abstraction clarification. Java

Tags: java, class, abstract

Hello I have just been learning about abstraction and was looking for a bit of clarification.

1 - Is the only reason for using an abstract method to be able to pass static type checking without actually having to implement the method? Is there any other reason why someone would want to make a method abstract?

2 - If you made an abstract method and had some code in it, how would you "add to" that code in the sub class implementation. Would you just carry on typing? I have only seen empty abstract methods in examples.

Thanks and sorry if these questions are a bit basic.

Comment: What do you mean by _pass static type checking without actually having to implement the method_? Also, read a tutorial on `abstract` classes.

Comment: Well the actual quote from my lecture slides is "Abstract methods allow static type checking without requiring implementation." What I understood that meant is if you call a method on the object while the object type is it's "superclass", it won't give you an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 1: abstract methods are a way to suggest to a programmer that extends your code, that "there should be a method like this implemented in your code". This may be used to pre-design interfaces in some bigger systems, for example.

At 2: yes. When implementing sub-classes of some abstract classes you are not restricted only to the methods and fields of your "parent" class.

Comment: Note that abstract methods can not have a body though (which question 2 was about).

Comment: Abstract classes, like interfaces, allow you to specify a kind of contract between you (your class) and your user (the user of your class). The difference to interface is that you can also provide some behaviour, that is you can implement some methods and leave other methods empty, that is abstract.

Comment: Of course, but using proper naming, return type and paramethers you can give kind of a suggestion, right? For example, you may have abstract class Figure, including abstract method area(), to be implemented in its inheritants.

Comment: So you can't have a body in an abstract method. That makes more sense.

Comment: That's why we call it "abstract" as it is not doing anything, just suggesting some solution/design.

Comment: Just one final question; would that make the sole purpose of an interface for solution/design, as all the methods in an interface are assumed to be abstract?

Comment: That is how it is most commonly used, and to tell the truth I can see no other use of it where it would be much helpful. Interfaces only contain abstract methods, so they only suggest future implementation/extending. Abstract classes may contain abstract methods as well as standard, non-abstract methods, so they can both suggest future implementation and implement some functionality at the same time (in different methods though). Note that a class that contains at least one abstract method must be declared as abstract, even if all the other methods are non-abstract.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes, like interfaces, allow you to specify a kind of contract between you (your class) and your user (the user of your class). The difference to interface is that you can also provide some behaviour, that is you can implement some methods and leave other methods empty, that is abstract.

An abstract method is always empty - that's what it means to be abstract. Subtypes of an abstract class can change behaviour of a method implemented in the abstract parent by implementing the method themselves. They can reuse the parent's code by calling the parent's method first - like you do with constructors.

Comment: How can you "call parent's method" when it is abstract?

Comment: You can call a parent's method that is not abstract. The parent class is abstract but contains an implemented method.

Comment: "Subtypes of an abstract class can change behaviour of a method implemented in the abstract parent by implementing the method themselves. They can reuse the parent's code by calling the parent's method first" - may be just some unfortunate phrasing, but as for me it clearly sounds as if you suggested reusing by calling abstract-parent's method first.

Comment: Well, perhaps my phrasing really is unfortunate. Can you suggest an improvement?

Comment: Personally, I would not write about calling methods in terms of abstract methods at all. I do not get the idea of what you intended to say, so I am not sure about how it could be improved. Emphasis that only non-abstract methods may be called by class' children or do not write about it at all, maybe.

Comment: Yes, only non-abstract methods can be called: "Subtypes of an abstract class can change behaviour of a *method implemented* in the *abstract parent*" The only real callable code in the abstract parent are the methods that are implemented - my last sentence refers to them: ". They can reuse the parent's code by calling the parent's method first ..." I simplified and talked only about "a method implemented in the parent". A more rigorous description could  be a tad tedious. I'll try to think about it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1 - abstract classes are meant to be extended by a regular class. so by having abstract methods, it forces the implementation of the abstract method in the class extending the abstract class, however, it also gives control to the programmer on how it should be implemented. lets say the class Lion and class Dog both extend the class Animal. lets say Animal class has run() method. both lion and dog can run but the way they run, how fast they run is different. thus, by making run() abstract, you can define run() specifically to Lion and Dog classes.

2 - abstract methods can't have a method body or any code inside.
For example: abstract void run();
notice there are no starting and closing braces after run();